# Does a quick format on SSD let me reinstall a fresh Windows?

Tags: ssd, format

There's something wrong with my Windows 10 after recent update and I want to reinstall my Windows 10 on my SSD but the problem is that if I do a fully formatting it will cost a big problem to my SSD lifespan and I don't want that to happen.

I decided to do a quick format on my SSD -- will that allow me to install a fresh new Windows 10? I have no idea how a quick format works compare to a full format.

Comment: Full format takes much longer and overwrites the entire drive, quick format is quick and does no overwrite the drive. You can do a clean install with either.

Comment: Full format reads whole disk for read problems. It is not writing anything to sectors beside new filesystem creation. To clean all sectors on the drive you need to use software for shredding disks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a quick and full format?](http://superuser.com/questions/699784/what-is-the-difference-between-a-quick-and-full-format)

Comment: Stop being paranoid about writing to your SSD, there no need to concern yourself with it in this day and age.

Answer (score 3):

The wear on the SSD caused by a full-format is not really a problem. (At least, if you don't do it every day...)
Modern SSD's can take it easily.

But it isn't needed to do a re-install of Windows anyway. Just a quick format is enough and even that isn't really needed to do as a separate step...
When you boot from the Windows 10 install media and select a custom install you will be asked where (on which disk) you want to install it.
In that screen you can point at the existing partition(s) and delete them. Do that for each partition and just tell the installer to install to the empty disk (un-allocated space) that is left. This is effectively the same as doing a quick format before starting the installation.